# How to show nested (or 'tree') data in recycler view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a data structure where each node can contain n child nodes of the same type. I'd like to show these as a list where each child is intended as per its "depth". I have already a working recycler view that shows the top-level nodes. How would I go on about showing the child nodes?

The node class looks something like this:

```
public class Node
{
    private ArrayList<Node> children = new ArrayList<Node>();
    private String name;

    public Node(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addChild(Node node)
    {
        this.children.add(node);
    }

    public ArrayList<Node> getChildren()
    {
        return this.children;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Basically, the result I'd like to have is something like this:

```
Node A
    Node A's Child A
    Node A's Child B
Node B
    Node B's Child A
        Node B's Child A's Child A
        Node B's Child A's Child B
    Node B's Child B
        Node B's Child B's Child A
Node C
```

Comment: What should one item contain? just one line from mentioned or full base Node with subnodes...

Comment: One item should contain a single node's data, and the children of this node would be added under this node, intended (e.g. setting the left margin programmatically) according to the depth of the node.

Answer (score 3):

Hello This may be too late  to answer but still I found solution may be helps to you as well others

and thanks to **[TellH](https://github.com/TellH)** provide beautiful library

> https://github.com/TellH/RecyclerTreeView

- Create a Java bean class and implement the LayoutItemType, to attach item layout id to it.

  ```
  public class Dir implements LayoutItemType {
      public String dirName;

      public Dir(String dirName) {
          this.dirName = dirName;
      }

      @Override
      public int getLayoutId() {
        return R.layout.item_dir;
    }
  ```

  }
- Create a ViewBinder to bind view with the data bean. As you see, provideViewHolder(View itemView) corresponds for onCreateViewHolder in RecyclerView, and bindView corresponds for onBindViewHolder in RecyclerView.

  ```
  public class FileNodeBinder extends    TreeViewBinder<FileNodeBinder.ViewHolder> {
    @Override
    public ViewHolder provideViewHolder(View itemView) {
      return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(ViewHolder holder, int position, TreeNode node) {
       File fileNode = (File) node.getContent();
       holder.tvName.setText(fileNode.fileName);
    }

    @Override
    public int getLayoutId() {
        return R.layout.item_file;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends TreeViewBinder.ViewHolder {
      public TextView tvName;

      public ViewHolder(View rootView) {
         super(rootView);
         this.tvName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
     }
    }
  }
  ```
- Add TreeNode to TreeViewAdapter.

  ```
    List<TreeNode> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
      TreeNode<Dir> app = new TreeNode<>(new Dir("app"));
      nodes.add(app);
      app.addChild(
              new TreeNode<>(new Dir("manifests"))
                      .addChild(new TreeNode<>(new     File("AndroidManifest.xml")))
      );

       app.addChild(
          new TreeNode<>(new Dir("java")).addChild(
                  new TreeNode<>(new Dir("tellh")).addChild(
                          new TreeNode<>(new Dir("com")).addChild(
                                  new TreeNode<>(new Dir("recyclertreeview"))
                                          .addChild(new TreeNode<>(new File("Dir")))
                                          .addChild(new TreeNode<>(new File("DirectoryNodeBinder")))
                                          .addChild(new TreeNode<>(new File("File")))
                                          .addChild(new TreeNode<>(new File("FileNodeBinder")))
                                          .addChild(new TreeNode<>(new File("TreeViewBinder")))
                          )
                  )
          )
  );
   TreeNode<Dir> res = new TreeNode<>(new Dir("res"));
      nodes.add(res);
      res.addChild(
              new TreeNode<>(new Dir("layout"))
                        .addChild(new TreeNode<>(new File("activity_main.xml")))
                      .addChild(new TreeNode<>(new File("item_dir.xml")))
                      .addChild(new TreeNode<>(new File("item_file.xml")))
      );
       res.addChild(
              new TreeNode<>(new Dir("mipmap"))
                  .addChild(new TreeNode<>(new File("ic_launcher.png")))
      );
      TreeViewAdapter adapter = new TreeViewAdapter(nodes,     Arrays.asList(new FileNodeBinder(), new DirectoryNodeBinder()));
      rv.setAdapter(adapter);
  ```
- set TreeNodeListener to TreeViewAdapter

  ```
  adapter.setOnTreeNodeListener(new TreeViewAdapter.OnTreeNodeListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onClick(TreeNode node, RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
              if (!node.isLeaf()) {
                  //Update and toggle the node.
                  onToggle(!node.isExpand(), holder);
              }
              return false;
          }

          @Override
          public void onToggle(boolean isExpand, RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
              DirectoryNodeBinder.ViewHolder dirViewHolder = (DirectoryNodeBinder.ViewHolder) holder;
              final ImageView ivArrow = dirViewHolder.getIvArrow();
              int rotateDegree = isExpand ? 90 : -90;
             ivArrow.animate().rotationBy(rotateDegree)
                       .start();
          }
      });
  ```